# Can't increase the size of the logo in the header of my website

Tags: wordpress, image, header

I uploaded a new logo to my website (in header section) and I seem to have problem with increasing its size to full height of the header.

LINK to website.

http://icnmnaturopathy.eu/en/

Answer (score 0):

seems the wrapper of the image (the a tag) has a specific width

```
a.logo { 
width: 290px;
}
```

thats why the image wont grow in size, in further inspection i see the you contained this section in "col-sm-2 col-xs-12 navigation-header" and then gave the a tag a bigger width length then it should... it might cause you some problems on the responsive side :)

keep practicing! you're doing great!